# Melted biscuits

Tags: baking, cookies, sugar-free

When I was young, my mother had us on a non-wheat non-sugar diet for reasons.  So she made some sweet biscuits that were sugar-free (had honey or something in them instead of sugar - or something - not sugar-free i.e. simple carbs free, it was an allergy thing).

She forgets what she put in them or how she made them.  I have no idea.  But they *melted* across the tray, becoming flat and uniform, and when done they tasted like nothing I have ever eaten since.  Any idea what the hell they were and how I can reproduce that melting/delicious effect?

Comment: Most biscuits (cookies for our American friends) melt across the tray when you bake them, so that doesn't really narrow it down. In any case, recipe requests are off-topic here on Seasoned Advice - I'm sure Google will give you any number of sugar free, wheat free cookie recipes.

Comment: From the description of the 'melting', it sounds like oatmeal lace cookies, but most of those have a little bit of flour in them.

Comment: Melted into a flat sheet.  Like, brownies, I guess.  They *dripped* down the side of the oven.  We cut them up with a knife and ate them as squares.  Substitute wheat flours or sugar substitutes that do melt like that so I can experiment with them is what i'm after.

Comment: I want to know which things in those categories might cause melting, or if everything in that category melts so the melting doesn't narrow it down.  'sugar free biscuit recipes' is nothing like what I am after at all.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds a bit like a paleo version of Anzac biscuits. If not, please don't bite my head off, but here's the recipe I follow, although I don't recall where I obtained it originally;

**Pre-heat oven to 150C**

175g organic rolled oats

40g dessicated or flaked organic coconut

60g flaked or chopped almonds - or almond meal if preferred

2 1/2 tablespoons cold pressed olive, coconut or macadamia nut oil

2 tablespoons honey

1/2 teaspoon vanilla bean paste

1 tablespoon water

Mix it together in one big, gooey, mess, adding a little of the water if needed to help keep it together.

Form into balls, place on tray, then flatten with the back of a fork.

Chuck in the oven for 20-30 minutes or until golden brown.

***Note**; Mine tend to come out very 'chewy', melty and more-ish, which is just the way I like them.